# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 0 Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to store  data(1stName,lastName,email,password,gender all of them inside an object and the object is inside the array) inside the localStorage and I used JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() functions. I don't know where is the error.
Note that I only write just javascript.
Here is the code:

```
<script>

function create(){

if(document.getElementById('fn').value!=null&&document.getElementById('fn').value!=""
&&document.getElementById('ln').value!=null&&document.getElementById('ln').value!=""
&&document.getElementById('em').value!=null&&document.getElementById('em').value!=""&&
document.getElementById('pass').value!=null&&document.getElementById('pass').value!=""){

if(document.getElementById('gender_Male').checked) {
var acc = {fname:document.getElementById('fn').value,
lname:document.getElementById('ln').value,
email:document.getElementById('em').value,
password:document.getElementById('pass').value,
gender:document.getElementById('gender_Male').value};}

else{
var acc = {fname:document.getElementById('fn').value,
lname:document.getElementById('ln').value,
email:document.getElementById('em').value,
password:document.getElementById('pass').value,
gender:document.getElementById('gender_Female').value};}


if (localStorage.getItem('acc')) 
var ar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('acc')); 
else 
var ar = [];



ar.push(acc);   
  localStorage.setItem('acc',JSON.stringify(ar));




}
else window.alert("One of the above is empty");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check with this

```
let ar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('acc') || []);
ar.push(acc);   
localStorage.setItem('acc',JSON.stringify(ar));
```

Comment: what you are getting by printing this localStorage.getItem('acc');
hide the code from the line  if (localStorage.getItem('acc'))

Comment: I want to use the the array of object that it's inside the storage to another page as an account page

Comment: jsut comment all your code from if(localStorage.getIem('acc'))
and print localStorage.getItem('acc'); and show me the output

Comment: the output was the last thing I have stored in it which is the first name(this was before I put it in object)